# How to add custom dialog for AccountPicker in android?

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog, accountpicker

below is my code to get email accounts of device and I want to use custom dialog box for google's account picker:

```
Intent intent = AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent(
    null, 
    null,
    new String[] { GoogleAuthUtil.GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_TYPE },
    false,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null
);

startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

It's showing a default dialog box, I want to change it to be like playstore's account switcher dialog, but I don't know how to add custom dialog in place of default dialog box in account picker.